# Access Denied Despite Correct Ranger KMS Group Settings

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

In Ranger KMS, we currently have the below value set.

```
key.acl.genomicskey.DECRYPT_EEK= nobody genomicusers
```

However, as a member of `genomicusers`, I am receiving the following error when attempting to use a Spark script to read and write to this location:

```
hail.java.FatalError: AuthorizationException: User:<me> not allowed to do 'DECRYPT_EEK' on 'genomicskey'

Java stack trace:
org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException: User:<me>not allowed to do 'DECRYPT_EEK' on 'genomicskey'
        at

Hail version: 0.1-e6de01c
Error summary: AuthorizationException: User:<me>not allowed to do 'DECRYPT_EEK' on 'genomicskey'
```

Looking in HDFS, the location I am trying to access is encrypted by this key.

```
/projects/genomics              genomicskey
```

HDFS access for the genomics folder looks like:

```
drwxrwxr-x   - hive    genomicusers           0 2017-06-13 11:03 /projects/genomics
```

Are there any additional changes I would need to make in Ranger to fix this?

Comment: were you able to solve this issue ? If yes please suggest.

Comment: Yes, if I recall correctly it was tied to a KMS setting involving blacklisted users/groups. When I have some time I'll see if I can dig up exactly what we did and post it as a solution.

Comment: in my case I dont have this user blacklisted but still I am not able to access the key